# validate Unique users in 2 columns sharepoint List

Tags: 2013, list, validation

I have a list which stores information about new sharepoint site requests. Where i have 2 fields (people and Groups)

- Primary Site Collection Admin
- Secondary Site Collection admin

Both of this fields are pointing to SpSite owners Groups in the site.
Now when users are filling up the NewForm.aspx i need to validate that they are unique users.

How do we do that?
Code I am using is:

```
<script language="javascript" src="/sites/services/SiteAssets/scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">

function PreSaveAction()
{
var PickerPerson1 = getPickerInputElement("Primary_x0020_Site_x0020_Adminis_41bc75f7-fb89-4d45-897a-372aee8074b6_$ClientPeoplePicker");

alert(PickerPerson1);

}

 function getPickerInputElement(identifier) 
   {   
      var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('DIV');   
      for (var i=0; i < tags.length; i++) 
      {       
       var tempString = tags[i].id;           
       if ((tempString.indexOf('UserField_upLevelDiv') > 0))
    {   
        if(identifier == tempString)
       { 
       var innerSpans = tags[i].getElementsByTagName("SPAN");     
         for(var j=0; j < innerSpans.length; j++) 
          {   
           if(innerSpans[j].id == 'content') 
             {   
              return innerSpans[j].innerHTML;  
             } 
          }   
       }     
       }   
      }   
      return null;   
   } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use SharePoint JavaScript `PreSaveAction()` ([Example](http://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2014/06/sharepoint-presaveaction-helps-for-actions-before-saving-an-item/)) to validate the data in the two fields. The people picker values can be read by using either Javascript or spjs-utility.js or SPUtility.js

```
function getPickerInputElement(identifier) {
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('DIV');
for (var i=0; i &lt; tags.length; i++) {
var tempString = tags[i].id;
//alert('tags[' + i + '].id = ' + tempString);
if ((tempString.indexOf(identifier) &gt; 0) &amp;&amp; (tempString.indexOf('UserField_upLevelDiv') &gt; 0)){
//alert('HIT for ' + identifier + ' id=' + tags[i].id + ' value=' + tags[i].value);
var innerSpans = tags[i].getElementsByTagName("SPAN");
for(var j=0; j &lt; innerSpans.length; j++) {
//alert('innerSpans[' + j + '].id = ' + innerSpans[j].id);
if(innerSpans[j].id == 'content') {
//alert('HIT for ' + identifier + ' id=' + innerSpans[j].id + ' innerHTML=' + innerSpans[j].innerHTML);
return innerSpans[j].innerHTML;
}
}
}
}
return null;
}
```

**Usage**

```
var person = getPickerInputElement("ff18");
```

See here for information: http://www.balestra.be/2011/11/get-the-value-of-a-sharepoint-people-picker-field-via-javascript.html

Or use [spjs-utility.js](http://spjsblog.com/2013/08/20/spjs-utility-js-v1-17/)

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
    var myPeoplePickerValue = getFieldValue("MyPeoplePickersFieldInternalName","","; ","loginName");
    alert(myPeoplePickerValue);
},'sp.ribbon.js');
```

Or [SPUtility.js](http://sputility.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=People%20fields)

```
var peopleField = SPUtility.GetSPField('Assigned To');
```

Comment: Thank You for your response Nadeem, is there more of a OOTB inbuilt feature to implement that.

Comment: This could have been done using Calculated Columns but unfortunately SharePoint does not support person or group fields in calculated columns.

Comment: Nadeem I added the following to my CEWP in the Newform.aspx page but i got null value returned from the function. Any idea of such behavior. If the value is numm how can i compare with another control:

       <script language="javascript" src="/sites/services/SiteAssets/scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">
    function PreSaveAction()
    {
    var PickerPerson1 = getPickerInputElement("Primary_x0020_Site_x0020_Adminis_41bc75f7-fb89-4d45-897a-372aee8074b6_$ClientPeoplePicker");
    
    
    alert(PickerPerson1);
    
    }
</script>

Comment: Does this javascript work for sp2013

Comment: @allegrooctopus, I haven't tested it.